# Tabs in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, tabs

I'm new with Backbone and I'm making an example app in which I have to include tabs. The thing is that I have a collection of cities and I want to create one tab for each city (the collection fetchs from the server). I made a view called TabsView, which in the render function passes the collection to a template, and this one loops through the collection and renders the tabs.

What I want to do is that the first tab appears as 'active'. What I've done for the moment is that each tab has a href to a route in the router which changes it's class to active using jquery. Don't know if this is the best way to do this but it works. Maybe there's a better way. Also, when the user clicks a tab, I want to be able to render other view.

Hope I made myself clear. Thanks, cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 4):

Ok I solved this problem doing something like the following:

```
var Tabs = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: JST['tabs'],

  events: {
    'click li' : 'switchTab'
  },

  tagName: 'ul',

  className: 'nav-tabs',

  render: function() {
    this.renderTabs();
    return this;
  },

  renderTabs: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ cities: this.cities }));
    this.$('li:first').addClass('active');
  },

  switchTab: function(event) {
    var selectedTab = event.currentTarget;
    this.$('li.active').removeClass('active');
    this.$(selectedTab).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

It works fine, maybe it can be improved.